# How can I add base URL and additional parameters in this Segue

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboardsegue

Here is my code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    let playerViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! PlaybackViewController

    playerViewController.videoID = channelsDataArray[selectedVideoIndex]["ID"] as! String
}
```

How can I add base URL and additional parameters in this `Segue`?

Comment: What are you asking?

Answer (score 1):

Any additional data you wish to send to your segued view controller you can write as parameters in that view controller.

In the view controller class:

```
var varName = value
```

Inside prepare for segue:

```
playerViewController.varName = newValue
```

You can repeat this process for any additional data you need.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you correctly, you want to pass something in segue?

You can do it will something like this:

```
let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
self.performSegueWithIdentifier(segueIdentifier, sender: url)
```

Then in your `prepareForSegue` method do:

`playerViewController.baseUrl = sender as! NSURL`